# Finding the most occuring value of an attribute for a certain user in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of messages in a MongoDB. The message hold an ID, a user_id, a name, etc... 
But the record also hold a mood. This mood is a string that the user can choose. It's usually happy, sad or anything close to this.

What I need to achieve is an aggregate that provides a result-set with the most sent mood for each user. Example:

ID - Most frequent mood - Occurences of this mood
408800 - HAPPY - 4

So far I have achieved an overview of the amount of times a user has sent a message including a certain mood. I've done this with following aggregate.

```
db.getCollection("Output").aggregate([
{
    $group: {
        _id: { id: '$user_id', mood: '$mood' }, amount: { $sum: 1 }
    }
},
{
    $project: {
        _id: 1,
        userid: "$_id.id",
        mood: "$_id.mood",
        Ocurrances: { "$toInt": "$amount" }

    }
}])
```

The output I receive now, covers all of the moods for all of the users. But I only need to show the most frequent mood for each user.

I have been Googling for a while now but I don't seem to find an answer. I hope anyone can help me.

Comment: So now you've documents grouped on mood with their count, So all you need is to get the highest Occurrences one out ? Can you please provide some sample doc's?

Comment: I have got the documents grouped as per how many times a certain user has sent us a certain mood. For example, the script above tells you that user A has sent us 2 times that he was HAPPY and 4 times that he was sad. I need to achieve an overview of every user and the mood he has sent us the most frequent. This would for user A be SAD. This would come down in the table view (example: USER A - Happy - 4 times, USER B - SAD - 7 times). I can link you with an example json I'm also using. 
https://mega.nz/#!CjIX0IYJ!pRtHChWSm_AD-EodTCMXRTIHny3HuzjIEr93B2bo-nE

Comment: uhh, It's a large file i.e; 9mb json file, literally my text editors is getting hung, Can you please give the result of an ideal user with original doc of the same user